# Kubernetes - Get Node Label from Container

Tags: kubernetes

Is there any way to get a node labels from within a container for use as an environment variable?

It's similar to this https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/, but I need to use a label from the node for injecting into the container instead.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to get node labels without sending some requests to the k8s api server. You could do that - but that would mean every pod will need read access and that's not great security wise.

How about an alternate solution - if you need to make sure the pod is running on nodes with specific labels, you can use [taints and tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/) to achieve that more easily.

Comment: I actually needed to pick up some metadata from the node level for use as an environment variable when starting up. This is needed by the application we're using. I get that taints and tolerations will be good for pod placement, but that's not the use case.  However, thanks for sharing your thought on getting the labels passed through; I suspected it, but couldn't find information to confirm this one way or another. Thank you, and considered to be solved.